# Golang logrus logs available in console but not being sent to loggly

Tags: logging, go, gorilla, loggly

I have a golang project and I'm trying to use loggly logging as explained in their blog at https://www.loggly.com/blog/logging-to-loggly-from-go-with-logrus-and-logrusly/

The problem is that with their example, things are fine but I have a bunch of files and dozens of functions (which handle API calls) and I don't want to go about re-initializing the logger instance every time.

This works perfectly in main.go

```
log := logrus.New()
hook := logrusly.NewLogglyHook(logglyToken, domain, logrus.WarnLevel, logglyUsername, logglyPassword)
log.Hooks.Add(hook)
log.Info("Welcome")
hook.Flush()
```

and I'm able to see this message in my loggly account.

But, if I do something like this -

```
func LogrusLogger(loglevel string, message interface{}){
    log := logrus.New()
    hook := logrusly.NewLogglyHook(logglyToken, domain, logrus.WarnLevel, logglyUsername, logglyPassword)
    log.Hooks.Add(hook)

    log.Info(loglevel, message)
    hook.Flush()
}
```

then upon calling this function, the logs can be seen in the program console but not in the loggly account specified.
Am I calling the hook.Flush() correctly? (Because I'm assuming that's the point where the logs get sent to the loggly server)

Additional info:
The first piece of code is in `main.go` inside the `main()` function

The second piece of code is in `utility.go` which has a package utility and I call the function as `utility.LogrusLogger(loglevel, message)` wherever I want after importing the package utility in that file.
I'm pretty sure things are fine as I'm able to see the logs in the program console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by declaring the following globally

```
log := logrus.New()
hook := logrusly.NewLogglyHook(logglyToken, domain, logrus.WarnLevel, logglyUsername, logglyPassword)
```

and then using functions like this -

```
func LogrusInfo(args ...interface{}) {
    logger.Hooks.Add(hook)
    logger.Info(args...)
    hook.Flush()
}
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30261304/4720042