# How to write logs to multiple log files in golang?

Tags: go, logging

I am writing an application in which i need to record logs in two different files. For Example **weblogs**.go and **debuglogs.go**. I tried using the **log4go** but my requirement is i need the logger to be created in main file and be accessible in sub directory as major of decoding and logging is done in sub file. Can anybody please help with that?

Comment: https://www.scalyr.com/blog/go-logging, https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30257622/golang-logrus-how-to-do-a-centralized-configuration

Comment: https://awesome-go.com/#logging you can find list of popular logging packages here.

Comment: What's stopping you from passing the loggers from main to the things that need them? It's not clear what exactly you need help with.

Comment: @Peter I have my logger declared in my main function in my parent package. I wanted to access the same logger variable in sub directory. Since you cannot import main, i am not getting a way to make my logger variable accessible in sub package .

Comment: Loggers are just values. You can pass them down as function arguments or in struct fields, for example. If you really want to use globals, make a new package that *can* be imported and initialize it in main.

Answer (score 8):

Here's one way to do it, using the standard `log` package:

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    f1, err := os.Create("/tmp/file1")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer f1.Close()

    f2, err := os.Create("/tmp/file2")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer f2.Close()

    w := io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout, f1, f2)
    logger := log.New(w, "logger", log.LstdFlags)

    myfunc(logger)
}

func myfunc(logger *log.Logger) {
    logger.Print("Hello, log file!!")
}
```

Notes:

1. `io.MultiWriter` is used to combine several writers together. Here, it creates a writer `w` - a write to `w` will go to `os.Stdout` as well as two files
2. `log.New` lets us create a new `log.Logger` object with a custom writer
3. The `log.Logger` object can be passed around to functions and used by them to log things

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can manage logs for debugging and prod envoirments with multi log files:

First, make a type for managing multiple loggers you can make a separate file for this like `logging.go`

```
type LOGGER struct {
        debug *log.Logger
        prod  *log.Logger
        .
        .
        .
    }
```

For getting the `LOGGER` pointer anywhere in your project the best approach will be to get it through the [singleton pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/singleton/go/example#example-0) like

```
    var lock = &sync.Mutex{}
    var loggers *LOGGER

    func GetLoggerInstance() *LOGGER {
      lock.Lock()
      defer lock.Unlock()

    if loggers == nil {
      fmt.Println("Creating LOGGER instance now.")
      loggers = &LOGGER{} 
    } else {
        fmt.Println("LOGGER instance already created.")
    }

    return loggers
}
```

Now setup logger for debug env in any pkg or directory level better is to setup it at the root level

```
    logger := GetLoggerInstance()
    f, err := os.OpenFile("path/to/debug/log/file", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("debug log file not created", err.Error())
    }
    loggers.debug = log.New(f, "[DEBUG]", log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lmicroseconds|log.LUTC)

    loggers.debug.Println("This is debug log message")
```

With the same approach, you can also create prod or as many as you want.

```
    logger := GetLoggerInstance()
    f, err = os.OpenFile("path/to/prod/log/file", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("prod log file not created", err.Error())
    }
    loggers.prod = log.New(f, "[PROD]", log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lmicroseconds|log.LUTC)

    loggers.prod.Println("This is prod log message")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [Go package "go_multi_log"](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/takecontrolsoft/go_multi_log) for logging to multiple logs. I hope you can find my examples bellow useful.

```
import (    
  "github.com/takecontrolsoft/go_multi_log/logger"
  "github.com/takecontrolsoft/go_multi_log/logger/levels"
  "github.com/takecontrolsoft/go_multi_log/logger/loggers"
)
// Register file logger
f := loggers.NewFileLoggerDefault()
_, err := logger.RegisterLogger("file_logger_key", f)

// Usage
logger.Debug("Test log debug message")
logger.Info("Test log info message")
logger.Error(errors.Errorf("Test error object").Err)
logger.TraceF("Person: %v, Car: %v", person, car{Year: "2021"})
```

Console logger is initialized by default, but could be stopped.

```
logger.DefaultLogger().Stop()
```

Also any of the registered loggers could be stopped and later started as follow:

```
logger.GetLogger("file_logger_key").Stop()// or Start()
```

The log level could be set on the initialization or adjusted later. It is "Info" by default. Here are some examples:

```
f = logger.GetLogger("file_logger_key")
f.SetLevel(levels.Debug)
```

You can find in GitHub a simple example of [JsonLogger](https://github.com/takecontrolsoft/go_multi_log?tab=readme-ov-file#custom-logger) implementation. Any custom logger could be registered as follow:

```
logger.RegisterLogger("json_key", NewJsonLogger(levels.Info))
```